# Node js, unresolved multer().single

Tags: node.js, post, express, fileupload

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь загрузить на сервер файл, интернет пестрит кучей примеров, как это сделать. Способ через multer показался довольно простым, но ошибка.

Вот кусок кода html:

```html
<form action="/data" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="file" name="filefield" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Вот кусок кода js:

```js
import express  from 'express';
const app = express();

var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest : 'src/uploads/'});

app.post('/data', upload.single('filefield'), function (req, res, next) {
        res.send(req.files)
    });
```

Проблема в том, что выдает ошибку Unresolved function or method single().

Multer использую последней версии.
Что может быть не так? Или может есть способ проще?

Comment: а если прописать upload.any() - то приходит файл?

Comment: будет ошибка unresolved function or method any().

Comment: попробуйте установить предыдущую версию `multer:" ^1.2.0"`

Comment: пробовал и на более ранние откатываться, та же проблема

Comment: а какой express и node?

Comment: express": "^4.14.0, node 6.9.4

Comment: не знаю.. у меня `express: "^4.14.0", multer:" ^1.2.0",  node: 6.6.0 `  все работает...

Answer (score 0):

В чем косяк с single() так и не ясно, но файл удалось загрузить через express-fileupload:

```js
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/data', function (req, res, next) {
    var sampleFile;

    if (!req.files) {
        res.send('No files were uploaded.');
        return;
    }

    sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;

    sampleFile.mv('./uploads/filename.png', function(err) {});
    next();
});
```

И да, этот способ тоже не работал, пока не исправил enctype на encType. Возможно были конфликты с кучей других библиотек для скачки файлов, которые я устанавливал, пробуя разные способы. Их я тоже удалил.